# convert a list (object?) of 1*5 to a df in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following `results` list (can be much larger):

```
['2017-09-01.csv', -322.0, -6.5, 99.0, 41, '2017-09-04.csv', -31.0, 3.5, 78.5, 30]
```

it's format is 5*1, 5*1, etc.

I am looking for the following results:

```
Date              A       B    C      D
    '2017-09-01.csv', -322.0, -6.5, 99.0, 41,  
    '2017-09-04.csv', -31.0, 3.5, 78.5, 30
```

and I was trying to use the following code to reshape it to a df:

```
x_sublists = [results[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(results), 5)]
df11 = pd.DataFrame(x_sublists [1:], columns=x_sublists [0])
```

which ended with:

```
print(df11.shape)
Columns: [(-322.0,), (99.0,), (2017-09-04.csv,), (3.5,), (30,)]
print(df11)
Index: []
```

I also tried this:

```
r_reshaped = np.array(results[5:], dtype=object).reshape((0, 5))
df11 = pd.DataFrame(r_reshaped, columns=results[:5])
```

which ended with:

```
print(df11.shape)
Columns: [(-322.0,), (99.0,), (2017-09-04.csv,), (3.5,), (30,)]
print(df11)
Index: []
```

thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reshape from numpy

```
import numpy as np



l=['2017-09-01.csv', -322.0, -6.5, 99.0, 41, '2017-09-04.csv', -31.0, 3.5, 78.5, 30]

pd.DataFrame(np.array(l).reshape((len(l)//5, 5)),columns=['data','A','B','C','D'])
Out[181]: 
             data       A     B     C   D
0  2017-09-01.csv  -322.0  -6.5  99.0  41
1  2017-09-04.csv   -31.0   3.5  78.5  30
```

Comment: cool it worked though it didn't kip the same order. I got:   data   A               B    C   D
0 -322  99  2017-09-04.csv  3.5  30 + it gave me only 1 line.... can it be that my 'results' is not a list???

Comment: @Giladbi yep seems like your list is not same order

Comment: Can it be b/c it's not a list? I am using results.appened to create it. results.append(store_predictions['Net_Pnl($)'].sum().round()) is one of the values.

Comment: @Giladbi yep, seems like it it tuple , try `results=[x[0] for x in results]`, then using my approach above